# Get char by ignoring escape characters

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping, ascii

Given this example:

```
var myString = "foo\rbar";
var myChar = myString[3];
var myCharCode = (int) myChar;
```

I want to get the CharCode 92 (`\`) instead of 13 (`\r`).

How can I achieve this? Something like these lines feel wrong:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\r", "\\r");
myString = myString.Replace("\n", "\\n");
//Repeat for every possible escape sequence
```

---

Full context:

I can not change `myString` because I get this from a database from a **legacy VB6 application**. In VB6, `\` and `r` are treated as seperated characters. In .NET they are treated as ASCI 13.

Maybe **VB6** save it not correctly to the database. However it is reading it correctly back to the VB6 client.

Comment: Have you tried getting the data from DB as `char[]`?

Comment: I am using the entity framework (DbFirst), I don't think this is possible @AlessandroD'Andria

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It's not just possible - it's the default behaviour! If I have a string that is `char 92 + char 114`, save that to a database, then read it back out, I will get back `char 92 + char 114`. I won't get back `char 13` because that's not what I saved to the database...

Comment: "In .NET they are treated as ASCII 13." This is not correct. _It is true only in C#, as a **literal** string._ I think your experiment shows that `'\u000d'` is truly being returned from the db. The VB6 client must be doing the equivalent to the .Replace that you are doing in C#. It's kind of strange to serialize string data that way. Are you sure you need to?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given, you simply need to tell the string not to treat the backslash as an escape character. In C#, you do this be prepending `@` to the string.

```
var myString = @"foo\rbar";
var myChar = myString[3];
var myCharCode = (int)myChar;
Console.WriteLine(myCharCode);
```

However, given you said something about reading this from a database, I'm not sure this answer is sufficient for your needs - however it is correct for your question. If you are just reading it from a database, and you are getting a (char)13 then it's because it was saved in the database as such...

Comment: I can not change this to a verbatin string, I get it from database.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt That's the bit I don't understand - if you read it from a database and it's char 13, then it's because it was *saved* to the database as such - unless you are doing some crazy processing on the database result...

Comment: Maybe the legacy VB6 client has some errors, but it is meant to be 92,82 instead of 13 @RB

Answer (score 0):

String escaping is working in the string literals in the code. You need to use `\\` to have single `\` in string.

`var myString = "foo\\rbar";`

Also you can use `@` character for unescaped strings:

`var myString = @"foo\rbar";`

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Upd:

If you are porting you application from the VB6 to C# you need to escape special characters in string literals. `foo\rbar` have different representations in VB6 and C# code.